# Как сделать такую же пагинцаию в slick slider'е?

Tags: slick.js

[image: Пагинация]

Как сделать так, чтобы страницы доходили до определённого количества, потом ставилось троеточие и в конце показывалась последняя страница? Собственно всё на фото.

Comment: Что у вас уже есть? Добавьте хотя бы готоывй слайдер через воспроизводимый "Фрагмент кода"

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Pagination {

    constructor(dotsSelector) {
        this.dotsSelector = dotsSelector;

        this.maxLinks = 5;
        this.maxOffset = Math.ceil(this.maxLinks / 2);

        document.querySelector(this.dotsSelector).innerHTML = '';
    }

    generate (currentSlide, countSlides) {

        this.currentSlide = currentSlide + 1;
        this.countSlides = countSlides;

        this.offset_left = this.currentSlide > this.maxOffset;
        this.offset_right = this.currentSlide <= this.countSlides - this.maxOffset;

        if (this.countSlides > this.maxLinks) {

            if (this.currentSlide <= Math.floor(this.countSlides / 2)) {
                this.generateLeftPosition();
            } else if (this.currentSlide > Math.floor(this.countSlides / 2)) {
                this.generateRightPosition();
            }

        } else {
            this.generateDefault();
        }

    }

    generateDot(i, text, className = false, current = false) {

        var dot = document.createElement('li');

        if (className) {
            dot.classList.add(className);
        }

        if (i != '' && this.currentSlide == i) {
            dot.classList.add('active');
        }
        
        dot.id = i - 1;
        dot.innerText = text;

        document.querySelector(this.dotsSelector).appendChild(dot);
    }

    generateLeftPosition() {

        if (this.currentSlide != 1) {
            for (var i = this.currentSlide - 1; i < this.currentSlide - 1 + this.maxOffset; i++) {
            this.generateDot(i, i, 'dot');
            }
            this.generateDot('', '...');
            this.generateDot(this.countSlides, this.countSlides, 'dot');
        } else {
            for (var i = this.currentSlide; i < this.currentSlide + this.maxOffset; i++) {
                this.generateDot(i, i, 'dot');
            }
            this.generateDot('', '...');
            this.generateDot(this.countSlides, this.countSlides, 'dot');
        }

    }

    generateRightPosition() {

        if (this.currentSlide != this.countSlides) {
            this.generateDot(1, 1, 'dot');
            this.generateDot('', '...');
            for (var i = this.currentSlide - 1; i < this.currentSlide - 1 + this.maxOffset; i++) {
            this.generateDot(i, i, 'dot');
            }

        } else {

            this.generateDot(1, 1, 'dot');
            this.generateDot('', '...');
            for (var i = this.countSlides + 1 - this.maxOffset; i <= this.countSlides; i++) {
                this.generateDot(i, i, 'dot');
            }
        }

    }

    generateDefault() {

        for (var i = 1; i < this.countSlides + 1; i++) {
            this.generateDot(i, i, 'dot');
        }

    }

}

function addListeners() {

    var dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
    dots.forEach(function(el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', function(){
            $('#slider').slick('slickGoTo', el.id);
        });
    });

}

$('#slider').on('init', function(event, slick){

    var pag = new Pagination('#dots');
    pag.generate(slick.currentSlide, slick.slideCount);

    addListeners();

});

$('#slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){

    var pag = new Pagination('#dots');
    pag.generate(nextSlide, slick.slideCount);

    addListeners();

});

$('#slider').slick();
```

```css
.dot.active {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Slick</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="slider">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div class="slide">4</div>
  <div class="slide">5</div>
  <div class="slide">6</div>
  <div class="slide">7</div>
  <div class="slide">8</div>
  <div class="slide">9</div>
  <div class="slide">10</div>
 </div>
 <ul id="dots"></ul>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Код написан быстро и ногами, но в целом наглядно показывает как достигнуть желаемого результата